# Adding standalone table into layout in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, layouts, table-frame

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.3 and I cannot figure out how to add a standalone table into my layout. It has important statistics on it that I need to show on the map.

On the Insert tab, the "Table frame" seems to just add layers from the map, not standalone tables.

Comment: What steps did you perform when you tried to insert a table frame into your layout?

Comment: Insert > "table frame" and then it only gives the option to insert the entire attribute table from one of the layers. I am not able to change the layer either.

Comment: Not sure if it was available in 2.3 but have you looked at table dynamic text? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/layouts/add-dynamic-text.htm#GUID-890A21B3-C174-48EF-A33A-CC6A83DC4AAA

Comment: That seems like it should be the right way to do it, but it still is only giving me the option to select the one layer. I'm wondering if this is a bug with 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to click on the layer you want in the layouts contents and then click "table frame".